# Cannot access a broken file

Tags: linux, file, ubuntu

I have some compiled binary in my `/usr/bin` folder and it seems to be broken, I cannot even delete it. A reboot does not fix the issue... pls help

```
root@plshelp:/# ls -la /usr/bin/ | grep myapp
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/myapp': Input/output error
-?????????  ? ?      ?              ?            ? myapp
root@plshelp:/# rm /usr/bin/myapp
rm: cannot remove '/usr/bin/myapp': Input/output error
```

I have no idea what the hell is going on...

Thx in advance

Comment: Is the file a symlink?

Comment: I'm afraid it's possible that your storage medium is dying.

Comment: Time for a fsck of the partition.